# How to ensure that the output of an inverter is High while it's input is High-Z

Tags: pcb-design, switches, schematics, inverter

This design is part of a board that Converts PCIE to USB using a Host Controller.
the host controller has an SPI ROM that I want to be able to flash in in two ways.
one way using the Host Controller itself (Signals: A6...A9) and the other way using external programmer called DEDIPROG (signals A0...A3).

I'm using [FSTU3384QSCX](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/FSTU3384%20Series.pd) bus switch, and I want to pass A0..A4 and A6..A9 according to OE1_bar and OE2_bar, where it's enable is controlled by VCC_DEDIPROG voltage that comes from programmer device that I use.

when VCC_DEDIPROG is High (3.3V) I want the other enable signal VCC_DEDIPROG_BAR to be low which will work fine due to the inverter.
but when we disconnect the programmer from power, VCC_DEDIPROG will be high-Z, and I want the output of the inverter (VCC_DEDIPROG_BAR) to be high.
how do I guarantee that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you let the input float there is no guarantee what the output will be.  Generally you will just add a pull-down resistor (i.e. a resistor from the input pin of the inverter to ground) that will pull the input to a logic 0 when the line is not being driven actively.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.